# Power BI Calculate MAX based on the Slicer Selections

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table which displays hourly pay per position. I'm using MAX(HourlyPay) to get the maximum value in the table and get a value 60 for example. But when I apply a slicer (based on department), the value still show's as 60. Is there a way to recalculate the MAX of HourlyRate based on the Slicers?

Tables:
Occupants
PayDetails (table which contains "Hourly Pay")
OrgStructure (table containing Department slicer)

Relationships:
Occupants to PayDetails (1:1)
Occupants to OrgStructure (*:1)

The column MAX(HourlyPay) which I'm trying to calculate is in the table Occupants.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Providing the relationship that you have added links to an identical value in each table, then the slicer should filter the hourly pay column as expected.